# How do I add a ghosting effect to a sprite?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, pixel-shader

I am trying to add multiple effects to sprite to learn how to do pixel and vertex shaders for 2D games in XNA. Unfortunately, many of the tutorials or example code go over my head, as I am new to shaders (or more correctly the [Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Effect%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) class). The effect I am looking for is like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZmTsoYevnI). Is this even possible to do with Effects or am I missing something?

Comment: No need to write a custom pixel shader for this. You could just draw multiple sprites with decreasing opacity along the path of movement.
As long as you submit the sprites in a single batch only one draw call will be needed.

Comment: @Lucius That makes a lot of sense, I would just have effectively have an after image object with a texture, position, and alpha, and when the alpha is less than or equal to zero, then remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with Lucius. Shaders are awesome but it is not a best fit for everything. [Here](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/how-to-generate-shockingly-good-2d-lightning-effects/) I found out a tutorial to create a effect only with 2D drawings. Many of the old 2D games generate effects like this only. As, at that moment graphics card was not that normal like now days are.

This kinda effect can be achieved by running multiple image, where one image is proper image while other is black and white of the image with shadow details. This will add sharpness to image which is needed for images.

And if you want particle based effect than also this tricks works to have two images instead of one for single particles and then give a effect / movement to that bundle of particles.

Have a look at tutorial. And let me know if more explanation is needed.